# How to control conversion error with struts2

Tags: struts2

i've got a form with 3 fields, two String (one select and a text field) and an int. When i put a letter or something else than an int (52.4 or aaa) in the field i got an error that i cannot "catch", my select disapear and on the message box i ve got a message from my validation xml file (in french) and another one in english (i suppose sent by struts).

error in tomcat :

```
(ognl.OgnlValueStack  60 ) Error setting expression 'userSize' with value '[Ljava.lang.String;@14aa6c3'
```

error on message box :

```
Invalid field value for field "userSize".
test size
```

JSP code :

```
<s:form action="sendUserCreation" method="POST">
<s:action namespace="/" name="civilityPicklist" executeResult="true"/><br />
<s:textfield name="lastName" /><br />
<s:textfield name="userSize" /><br />
```

struts.xml code :

```
<action name="createUser">
    <result>/jsp/user/create.jsp</result>
</action>
<action name="sendUserCreation" class="fr.action.UserAction" method="createUser">
    <result>/jsp/splash.jsp?messKey=${messKey}</result>
    <result name="input">/jsp/user/create.jsp</result>
</action>
<action name="civilityPicklist" class="fr.imaps.oxygene.portal.action.CivilityPicklistAction">
    <result>/jsp/user/civilityPicklist.jsp</result>
</action>
```

UserAction-validation.xml code:

```
<validators>
    <field name="userSize">
        <field-validator type="conversion">
            <message>test size</message>
        </field-validator>      
    </field>
</validators>
```

UserAction code :

```
private int userSize;

public int getUserSize() {
    return userSize;
}

public void setUserSize(int userSize) {
    this.userSize = userSize;
}
```

I thought the "conversion" validation type will "catch" this kind of problem but it seems not... what's wrong with my code ?

Comment: You don't show the important parts, like the rest of the `userSize` validation config and the property declaration/setter in the action. And what version of S2. Also, did you try an `Integer` instead of `int`?

Comment: struts version is 2.2.3, there is nothing else in the validation config, and same behaviour if i try with Integer :/, i'll edit my post with getter/setter in the action

Comment: Try putting an `int` validation in as well; I'll dig to see why the "conversion" validator is funky. Do you have a minimal example I could grab off of github? Either way, I'll look in to it before the end of the weekend--could be something broke in the validator itself.

Comment: i tried to put `int` validation, but get the same result. i don't have github account, i'll take a look at this.

Comment: I don't think it's your code. I'm getting exactly the same problem with the @ConversionErrorFieldValidator annotation. Two messages, one I'm also assuming is Struts generated and my message as well. I'm currently working around this by overriding the getFieldErrors() method and removing the unwanted messages. So I too would be interested in the fix for this.

Answer (score 0):

I've been taking a quick look at this and I think that the reason for the double message is that, in my case at least, it looks like conversion errors may be being handled twice, firstly by the StrutsConversionErrorInterceptor and again by the AnnotationValidationInterceptor. Both these interceptors are in the struts-default stack.

Removing the StrutsConversionErrorInterceptor from the stack removes the Struts generated message and leaves the user defined message as the only error message displayed. However, I've not had time yet to investigate any other side consequences of removing this inreceptor.